# Is there a workaround for lack of indicators in SSRS2008?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to use an indicator in one of my reports, however indicators are supported only in SSRS2008 R2 or newer, whereas I have only SSRS2008. Is there any workaround or other component which could imitate indicators and look similarly to the ones included in SSRS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding an expression-based image to the report, where the available images mimic the indicator you want to see.

In SSRS 2008R2, with some simple data:

[image]

I have set up a simple indicator:

[image]

[image]

Which works as you expect:

[image]

I've created a similar table in 2008, but instead of an indicator I have added an Image to that textbox, and three images to the report project:

[image]

[image]

The images are just indicator images, similar to the 2008R2 ones:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any similarity to the standard SSRS ones is purely coincidental, of course.

Set the image up like this:

[image]

i.e. Image Source to `External`.

The expression is:

```
=Switch(Fields!val.Value >= 0 and Fields!val.Value <= 3, "ind1.PNG"
    , Fields!val.Value >= 4 and Fields!val.Value <= 6, "ind2.PNG"
    , Fields!val.Value >= 7 and Fields!val.Value <= 10, "ind3.PNG")
```

So this is choosing the appropriate image based on our value. This works like a 2008R2 indicator:

[image]

I haven't mucked around with formatting so it's a bit rough, but you can see it works in principle so should work for you with a bit of tweaking.